# ORA-29279: permanent error: 554 5.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

get  ORA- 29279 relay access denied error.

see image for code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWalu.png)

```
enter code here
BEGIN

  UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => 'asd@gmail.com',

        recipients => 'sdfs@gmail.com',

        cc         => 'erte@gmail.com',

        bcc        => 'retr@gmail.com',

        subject    => 'UTL_MAIL Test',

        message    => 'If you get this message it worked!');

END;

/
```

Comment: Please, no images (or links to images.) Use formatted text instead!

Comment: I did not see the image. The website is blocked in turkey

Comment: Now u can see the code

Answer (score 0):

You have to get relay rights on that server ip then you can send e mail.